# Image AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR after upgrading to silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I'm having problems displaying a list of images on a ListBox, when some of the images don't initially exist.

After the missing images are created I try to reload them, but I still get AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR. Also I'm sure the images exist because I'm loading them from a flash memory I have, and I'm loading my Silverlight application via `D:\Work\SilverlightApplication2\SilverlightApplication2\Bin\Debug\SilverlightApplication2TestPage.html` so no other weird mambo-jumbo is going on.

**This setup works on Silverlight 4 but NOT on Silverlight 5.**

[Here's the full sample code](http://bit.ly/JFaVsR)

More details:

I created a Silverlight application with a ListBox. The ListBox is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `ThumbnailItem` each item from the list has a `ThumbnailPath` property which is a string to the path of an image.

The file at `ThumbnailPath` may not initially exist, but when I'm sure it exists, I call the  `PropertyChanged` event to notify whoever is bound the `ThumbnailPath` changed.

A simple way to test this is loading the Silverlight application without inserting the flash drive. After the images failed to load I insert the flash drive and hit the refresh button.

```
public class ThumbnailItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }
    public void NotifyThumbnailPathChanged() { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ThumbnailPath")); }
}

public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ThumbnailItem> lImages { get; set; }

    public MainPage() { ... }

    private void userControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //loading the list items            

        lImages.Add(new ThumbnailItem { ThumbnailPath = "F:/onlinePhotos2/262594030.jpg" });
        lImages.Add(new ThumbnailItem { ThumbnailPath = "F:/onlinePhotos2/1276943735.jpg" });
        lImages.Add(new ThumbnailItem { ThumbnailPath = "F:/onlinePhotos2/1632696970.jpg" });
        lImages.Add(new ThumbnailItem { ThumbnailPath = "F:/onlinePhotos2/1656387141.jpg.original.jpg" });
        lImages.Add(new ThumbnailItem { ThumbnailPath = "F:/onlinePhotos2/1699209377.jpg" });
    }

    private void ButtonRefresh_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //refreshing the list after the images exist 

        foreach (ThumbnailItem tsi in lImages)
        {
            string temp = tsi.ThumbnailPath;
            tsi.ThumbnailPath = null;
            tsi.NotifyThumbnailPathChanged();

            tsi.ThumbnailPath = temp;
            tsi.NotifyThumbnailPathChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**TL; DR; How to reload a binding to an image that didn't exist and now does**

Answer (score 1):

The structure of this code is a bit strange. Why did you make the change notification something external to the ThumnailItem class? The usual approach is to skip using an auto property and break out the setter in public string ThumbnailPath so it calls the change notification itself. That'll also help in your Loaded event where the change notification is never fired off, although controls are already bound to the collection at that point.

Like this:

```
public class ThumbnailItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _thumbnailPath;
    public string ThumbnailPath 
    {
        get { return _thumbnailPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || _thumbnailPath != value)
            {
                _thumbnailPath = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged("ThumbnailPath");
            }
        }
    }
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
    { 
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    }
}
```

Do *any* of the images show up? I wouldn't think so, because you're loading from the F drive in a plugin on the web page. You're accessing files cross-sceheme (http hosted, but files are local), and you're accessing files outside the sandbox.

To load from the F drive, you'll need to be a *Trusted* app running out-of-browser. Your project is an in-browser, untrusted app targeting the Silverlight 4 runtime. I wouldn't expect this to work in Silverlight 4 with the SL4 or SL5 runtimes. There's no way this code ever worked as written.

Hope that helps.

Pete

[NOTE: This was all written not realizing he was loading the Silverlight app from file:// - not a common approach]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it works at least when the flash is inserted. The code is sample code to isolate the issue. I attached a full working project to the question. And here's a screenshot http://bit.ly/JFhZWB Could you please consider taking a look. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Also remember that if I launch the `PropertyChanged` event on SL4 to notify the control, it works.

Comment: From the screen shot, I see you're running the html page locally, and not from a web server (even the built-in one). Realize that this will fail when/if you deploy to a site. I'll look at the code shortly.

Comment: actually, that sample code is what I was looking at (the dropbox zip file) when I answered the questions the first time around. I'll load it up in any case.

Comment: I downloaded your project, changed the file names to point to jpegs on a USB thumb drive I have, and it worked when running from the IDE. I clicked the button, and no changes.

Comment: Try this. Remove your flash drive. Load the project. Insert your drive. Hit the refresh button. Did they load? thanks for your time. Do you have SL5?

Comment: Hmm. Removed the drive, ran the app. No go. I need to head out, but I'll try and look into it later this evening if I get a chance. I still think a Silverlight app running locally from file:// is not a great idea, but we allowed it, so we have to support it :)

Comment: So I ran to another developer's computer and tested my steps and it also failed. Could it be the images I'm using? Here they are anyway in case you have any ideas http://bit.ly/JFpSeF I really appreciate the time you've taken to answer my question. Thanks

Comment: No, those images worked fine. It looks more like something that happens as a result of the files not being there when the app starts. I thought it had to do with the drive itself, but simply moving the files has the same effect. I'll try and look at it this evening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12046/discussion-between-pete-and-camilin87)

Answer (score 1):

`Image AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR`

The Image reference path is wrong (Or) the image not placed inside the client-bin folder. 
These are the reasons for `Image AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR` in Silverlight